# Mysql LEFT JOIN gets very slow above 25.000 rows

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join

The following query becomes suddenly extremly slow (seems not to finish at all) with more than approx **25.000** rows in table a (tried with adding limit x to the query):

```
select a.*, b.column 
  from table_a a
left join table_b b 
  on (a.message_id = b.message_id) 
where date_sub(curdate(), interval 30 day) < a.date 
  and ( 
        b.message_id is NULL or 
        ( 
          b.message_id is not NULL 
          and a.message_id = b.message_id 
          and b.redeemed > 0 
        )
      )
order by a.id DESC
```

there is an index on both `a.message_id` and `b.message_id`. table_a will have much more rows than `table_b`

I understand that the left join in combination with **is NULL** causes the mysql server reaches its limit, but I don't know how to rewrite the query to avoid the left join.

Basically I want to query table a and check if there is a matching entry in table b. If that is the case I want to consolidate the date from table b into the result.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest indexes on `(a.message_id,a.date,a.id)` and `(b.message_id,b.redeemed)`.

Comment: You can simplify the last condition: `… AND (  b.message_id IS NULL  OR  b.redeemed > 0  )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I simplified the last condition to

```
AND ( b.message_id IS NULL OR b.redeemed > 0 )
```

Now your query has this basic structure:

```
a LEFT JOIN b
WHERE b IS NULL
   OR b.x > 0   /* MySQL may or may not be able to optimize LEFT JOIN + OR*/
```

which I rewrote to a UNION:

```
a LEFT JOIN b
WHERE b IS NULL

UNION ALL

a INNER JOIN b /* LEFT -> INNER */
WHERE b.x > 0
```

So here is your complexified query:

```
(   SELECT
      a.*,
      NULL AS column  /* help MySQL a bit :) */
    FROM      table_a a
    LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.message_id = b.message_id

    WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) < a.date
      AND b.message_id IS NULL

) UNION ALL (

    SELECT
      a.*,
      b.column
    FROM       table_a a
    INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.message_id = b.message_id

    WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) < a.date
      AND b.redeemed > 0
)

ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

You can change the first subselect with LEFT JOIN to use NOT EXISTS, but I don't know if it helps:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  NULL AS column /* b's column(s) -> aliased NULL*/

FROM      table_a a

WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) < a.date
  AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM b
        WHERE a.message_id = b.message_id
      )
```

Comment: thanks for the union approach! Wasnt aware of that option. I tested and found that still the LEFT JOIN sub query SELECT a.*, b.column, FROM  table_a a LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.message_id = b.message_id is causing the issue. The second subquery is very performant. I wonder if the left join is still necessary at all as the union together with the inner join already combines everything?

Comment: I don't think that you could remove the left join, otherwise you couldn't get `a` rows without a matching `b` row.

Comment: wasnt able to make your last query work, mysql gives an error "syntax to use near 'WHERE..."

( 
 SELECT
      a.*, 
      NULL AS redeemed
    FROM      table_a a
 LEFT JOIN table_b b 
 ON ( a.message_id = b.message_id )
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT b.message_id
         WHERE a.message_id = b.message_id
   )
) UNION ALL (
    SELECT
      a.*,
      b.redeemed
    FROM       table_a a
    INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.message_id = b.message_id

    WHERE b.redeemed > 0
)

Comment: Sorry, that SELECT indeed had a syntax error, see the updated answer :)

Comment: I hope I helped a little bit. Don't forget adding the proper indexes if necessary (see eggyal's comment).